# How I can add SASL Authentication in my Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I've one Spring application which uses Kafka instance without any Authentication.

Now the story changes, Kafka moved out of Application and running as Cluster. I received Kafka Credential username and Password along with Hostname:port info.

What Other Information, I required to connect to Kafka Cluster.

Is there any Code Change is required? Or do I just I need to add some info in application-profile.yaml file?

I tried different approaches suggested in Google but it seems nothing works for me, I keep getting:

> Error:
>   Opening socket connection to server X1.X2.X3.X4/X1.X2.X3.X4:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)

```
hequeue:
    #To use local kafka, update use-mock-queue to false and add local  zkservers and metadata-broker-list
    use-mock-queue: false
    zkservers: X1.X2.X3.X4:2181,Y1.Y2.Y3.Y4:2181,Z1:Z2:Z3:Z4:2181
    metadata-broker-list: X1.X2.X3.X4:9092,Y1.Y2.Y3.Y:9092,Z1:Z2:Z3:Z4:9092
    properties:
        sasl:
            jaas:
                config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username='ANKIT' password='KOTAK';
            mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-256
            kerberos:
                service:
                    name: kafka
        security:
            protocol: SASL_SSL
```

Comment: That warning is from Zookeeper, not Kafka

Answer (score -1):

The following is one of the sample configurations with spring kafka how we are using. If it's matching you can try:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: 
    consumer:
      properties:
        isolation.level: 
        ssl.truststore.location: 
        ssl.truststore.password: 
        security.protocol: SASL_SSL
        sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
        sasl.kerberos.service.name:     
    producer: 
      properties: 
        ssl.truststore.location: 
        ssl.truststore.password: 
        security.protocol: SASL_SSL
        sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
        sasl.kerberos.service.name: 
    admin:
      properties: 
        ssl.truststore.location: 
        ssl.truststore.password: 
        security.protocol: SASL_SSL
        sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
        sasl.kerberos.service.name: kafka
```